# Insert specific bounded numbers into a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a SQL query that inserts incremental numbers that start in specific number (for example 100) and ends at another specific number (for example 3000) into a column of a table in SQL Server, but I don't know how to do this.

For example:
I want to insert 100 to 3000 into `categoryID` (column) from `Category` (table)

Thank you very much

Comment: Does the `categoryID` have `IDENTITY` set? It sounds like you are trying to doe something that is considered bad practice in database design: Having meaningful key values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 100
WHILE (@id <= 300)
BEGIN
    insert into categories (categoryID) values (@id)
    SELECT @id = @id + 1
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Same thing, but using recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @n INT
SET @i = 100
SET @n = 3000
;WITH t(c) AS (
    SELECT @i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c + 1 FROM t WHERE c < @n
)
INSERT INTO Categories(categoryID)
    SELECT c FROM t OPTION(MAXRECURSION 3000)
```